# Getting multiple select values from loop in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm looping through a list to populate my questionnaire with selects. I haven't found any tutorial explaining how to extract values from multiple selects in one click. Any ideas?

Here's the view:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Answer">
        @foreach (var question in Model.QuestionList)
        {
            <p>@question.Query</p>
            <select asp-for="Answer">
                <option value="">Select a number</option>
                <option value="@question.Option1">@question.Option1</option>
                <option value="@question.Option2">@question.Option2</option>
                <option value="@question.Option3">@question.Option3</option>
            </select>
        }
        <br>
        <br>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the .cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using myquiz.Models;
using myquiz.Services;

namespace myquiz.Pages
{
    public class QuizModel : PageModel
    {
        [ViewData]
        [BindProperty]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public Visitor Visitor { get; set; } 
        [BindProperty]
        public List<Question> QuestionList { get; set; } 
        public string Answer { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            ///QuestionList = new List<Question>();

            // if (QuestionList is null)
            //     QuestionList = new List<Question>();
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            Name = Visitor.Name;
            var quizService = new QuizService();
            QuestionList = quizService.GetQuestions();
        }

        public void OnPostAnswer() {
            Console.WriteLine("Yay, Answer works");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the model

```
namespace myquiz.Models
{
    public class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Query { get; set; }
        public string Option1 { get; set; }
        public string Option2 { get; set; }
        public string Option3 { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to get the select answers:

**The first way**

All the select lists have the same name `Answer`,so you could receive an array named `Answer` in the backend and use `BindProperty` to bind the values:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [ViewData]
    [BindProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Question1> QuestionList { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string[] Answer { get; set; }   //modify this...
    public void OnPostAnswer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yay, Answer works");
    }
}
```

View(be the same as yours):

```
<div class="text-center">
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Answer">
        @foreach (var question in Model.QuestionList)
        {
            <p>@question.Query</p>
            <select asp-for="Answer">
                <option value="">Select a number</option>
                <option value="@question.Option1">@question.Option1</option>
                <option value="@question.Option2">@question.Option2</option>
                <option value="@question.Option3">@question.Option3</option>
            </select>
        }
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

**The second way:**

If you want to get the question id with selected answer in `QuestionList`,you need learn how does model binding system work firstly:

For each property of the complex type, model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern `prefix.property_name`. If nothing is found, it looks for just `property_name` without the `prefix`.For `QuestionList` is a List,you need give the name like:`QuestionList[index].Answer`.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Answer">
        @{ 
            int i = 0;
        }                        //add this...
        @foreach (var question in Model.QuestionList)
        {
            <input hidden asp-for="QuestionList[i].Id" />          //add this..
            <p>@question.Query</p>
            <select asp-for="QuestionList[i].Answer">         //change asp-for
                <option value="">Select a number</option>
                <option value="@question.Option1">@question.Option1</option>
                <option value="@question.Option2">@question.Option2</option>
                <option value="@question.Option3">@question.Option3</option>
            </select>
            i++;         //add this...
        }
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:**

Change `<select asp-for="Answer">` to:

```
<select name="Answer">
     //..
</select>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! I just tried the first approach and as it shows on your video, the select isn't a dropdown list anymore. Any idea why and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @PabloAguirredeSouza,that is because the Answer in the backend is `string[]`,just remove `asp-for="Answer"` and modify select like: `<select name="Answer">`.